# React Native preload local images

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

How do I load images before Rendering in React Native

I use the map.

And i use custom image for markers.

I want to load the marker images before loading maps (or before rendering)

Comment: Is it a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42707080/preload-images-before-navigating-to-component ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

RN Image component a specific static method to handle this case: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#prefetch

Note: `Image.prefetch` returns a Promise

Below is an example of how to implement this using React Native Router Flux (RNRF), without using Redux:

```js
let urlOfImages = [https://...]

let preFetchTasks = []; 

urlOfImages.forEach((p)=>{
    preFetchTasks.push(Image.prefetch(p));
});

Promise.all(preFetchTasks).then((results)=>{
    let downloadedAll = true;
    results.forEach((result)=>{
        if(!result){
            //error occurred downloading a pic
            downloadedAll = false;
        }
    })

    if(downloadedAll){
        Actions.someScene({ downloadedPics: urlOfImages})
    }
})
```

Then in your **someScene** component use the image component like you normally do and the image will be fetched from your local disk cache rather then remotely :

```js
 <Image style={...} source={{uri: this.props.urlOfImages[0]}} />
```

Also just be aware you'll have issues if you attempt to load images from http rather than secured https endpoints: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8520

If you wanted to use it with Redux put the above code in an Action and make sure your reducers respond to the action and set the new state as per your application requirements.

Resource: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42710306/6569224