# Preload Images but don't show

Tags: react-native

I have 5 Images and when you tap on it, it renders the next one. The problem is, that an older phones it's very laggy. Is there a way to preload all 5 Images?

Comment: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/preloading-and-caching-assets/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preload images before navigating to component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42707080/preload-images-before-navigating-to-component)