# how to frequently re-render image in react native without making image flash?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a react native app and I need to render a "video" in the app. This "video" works by getting a new image from a url which updates the image every second.

This is my current implementation:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Image} from "react-native";

export default class CurrentWebcam extends React.Component { 
    constructor (props) {
        imagesource = {uri:'myurl?'+Date.now()};
        super(props)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.timer = setInterval(() => {
            imagesource = {uri:'myurl?'+Date.now()};
            this.forceUpdate();
          },3000)
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        clearInterval(this.updateTimer);
    }

    updatedImage(){
        return (
            <Image source={imagesource}
                   style={{width: 400, height: 400}} />
        )
    }

    render() { 
      return (
        <View> 
            {this.updatedImage()}
        </View> 
      );
    }
  }
```

The problem I am having is this method causes the image to flash out of existence every time it's re-rendered instead of simply changing from one image to the next. Also I know this is a really stupid system but I just have to work with it.

Comment: perhaps pre-loading the image in the interval and only updating `imagesource` after the image has loaded? Though, I have no clue how to do this in react native, but that's what I'd do in a browser - maybe something in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42707080/preload-images-before-navigating-to-component) will help you